# Too many windows 7 to select during Boot

Tags: windows-7, boot

Recently I have changed to my laptop the old HDD with a new SSD.
I messed up during the installation of windows 7. 
Now during the Boot I can choose 3 different windows 7.

### An example:

Windows 7
Windows 7

### Windows 7

The first works, but the other 2 not.
How can I modify it?
I want that the computer starts automatically with the first windows 7 without selecting it every time.

Comment: have you tried msconfig or easybcd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `msconfig.exe`, go to `Boot`, select the wrong entries and delete them

[image]

or use [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) to edit the boot manager and delete the 2 other options under `Edit Bootmenu`:

[image]

by selecting the broken entries and click on `delete`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change which option is loaded and how fast is the default used from Control panel -> System properties -> Startup and recovery.

Here is a detailed instruction: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/how-to-change-windows-7-boot-manager-options-to/0d5f2508-a70f-4a3a-a10c-4388a1acc34b?auth=1